# Pullig-Back Differential Forms by Mappings Almost Diffeomorphisms

Tags: complex-analysis, manifolds, differential-forms, diffeomorphism, complex-manifolds

Let $M,N$ be two complex manifolds of the same (complex) dimension.

Let $A$ be a subset of $M$ (not necessarily a sub-manitold).

Suppose $f: M \longrightarrow N$ is a map such that $f: M \setminus A \longrightarrow N\setminus f(A)$ is a diffeomorphism (or even a bi-holomorhpic).

Let $\omega$ be a differntial form on the manifold $N$.

Under the assumption above, can I bull-pack the differential form $\omega$ to the manifold $M$ by the restriction of the map $f$ on $M \setminus A$?

Comment: You can certainly use the regular pull back to take $\omega\in \Omega^n(N)$ to a form  $f^*\omega\in \Omega^n(M)$. You can also pull $\omega$ back by $f|_{M\backslash A}$ to get a form on $M\backslash A$, which is equal to $(f^*\omega)|_{M\backslash A}$

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter can I pull-back a differential form by a map that is not diffeomorphism?

Comment: Yes, a differential form can be pulled back by any smooth map as follows. For $\omega\in \Omega^n(N)$ we define $(f^*\omega)(v_1,\cdots, v_n)=\omega(T_pf v_1,\cdots, T_pf v_n)$ for $v_1,\cdots, v_n\in T_pM$. I'll leave it to you to verify that $f^*\omega$ is smooth.